# Eclipse does not detect Android device

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse is not detecting my phone. It's a Samsung Galaxy S2 HD LTE, Android version 4.0.4. Working in Windows 7. I have enabled USB debugging and updated the driver for it, but when I go into Eclipse **Run --> Run Configurations --> Target** it is not listed.

Not sure if this is relevant but I heard in another thread that the build target for your project has to be <= to the version of your device. If this is the case, all the options here are higher and there doesn't seem to be a way to add another so I'm not sure what to do. Also checked the manifest file to see what the min SDK is. It's 8 (which corresponds to android version 2.2) so that is fine.

[image]

I'm wondering if it has to do with **"Android"** being listed under Other Devices in the Device Manager (as per image below). I'm not even sure what this is. The phone itself says it's already updated, but when I try to update **Android** it can't find the driver software.

Another issue could be that when I connect the phone to my PC, it lists it as a camera instead of a mobile device, and displays the message "**Connected as a camera**" on the phone itself. The first time I connected, it also showed some error message about how device was not installed properly, but I haven't seen this message again and so not sure what to do about that, or that stupid Autoplay window that pops up every time I connect.

[image]

If you have any ideas please let me know!

Comment: Reboot your system and try again

Comment: For Samsung phones I had to install Kies, otherwise the ADB is not detecting them. That has worked for me.

Comment: @Aashish thanks I did but it didn't make a difference

Comment: As Steve pointed, install kies and reboot your device. S4 doesn't need such kind of setup. It automatically installs drivers once connected.

Comment: @Aashish mine is an S2 tho

Comment: @SteveBenett I installed Kies Air on my phone and followed the instructions to connect it to my PC. How is this supposed to help with Eclipse?

Comment: @user1985189 Install it on your PC, then all drivers of Samsung products will be available.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Android Composite ADB Interface is correctly installed.
You can refer [OEM USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) and [Debugging on real device](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice) for more details.

Comment: hey in regards to the OEM USB Drivers: I did this by browsing to the file location it said. It still couldn't find the driver software. As far as that second link goes, it doesn't give me any options when I click Run as... presumably because it's not detecting my device